# Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection failed when running Jenkins agent on MacOS

Tags: macos, jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

The below message is shown in Jenkins console after it runs properly for sometime, I am using MacOS High Sierra, with Java version 11 and Jenkins version 2.47.

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
FATAL: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from ‘myMacIP’ failed
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:575)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:596)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:517)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:996)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:987)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Downgrading to java version 8 fixed the issue. But this is not a long term solution, as our company policy forces us to use the latest Java Version.